# Deserialize string property to one object

Tags: java, json, jackson

We have a JSON message with one of the properties that we want to convert to a class:

```json
{
   "href": "/a/b/123",
   "name": "Sample"
}
```

```java
class Item {
  String name;
  ItemHref href;

  // Constructor and getters
}
class ItemHref {
  String value;
  // Constructor and getters
}
```

We would like to deserialize the `href` property as an instance of `ItemHref`. Unfortunately, we cannot find any way to achieve that.

A custom deserializer could be the solution. However, we have many type of "href" and we do not want to create a custom deserializer for all.

Does anyone, know how to deserialize one property to one object with Jackson?

**EDIT:**
We have tried to place `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` on the `ItemHref` constructor but we got the following error:

> failed: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `acme.ItemHref` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value (‘/a/b/123’)

Comment: See my minor update to my answer, I added the constructor for `ItemHref` explicitly, perhaps that was your mistake, as suggested by the error message you got.

The annotations are only required on `Item`, and if you only have one constructor, you can leave out @JsonCreator.

Comment: Did you try the full example I linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson's `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` annotations to specify a custom deserializer for a property in a JSON message.

Here is an example of how you could use these annotations to deserialize the href property in your JSON message as an instance of `ItemHref`:

```
    class Item {
      String name;
      ItemHref href;
    
      @JsonCreator
      public Item(@JsonProperty("href") ItemHref href, @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.href = href;
        this.name = name;
      }
      // getters

    }
    
    class ItemHref {
      String value;

      public ItemHref(String value) {
          this.value = value;
      }
      // getters
    }
```

The `@JsonCreator` annotation is used to specify a constructor or factory method to be used for creating instances of the class from JSON. The `@JsonProperty` annotation is used to specify the JSON property that the constructor or factory method parameter is mapped to.

In this example, the `Item` class has a constructor that takes `ItemHref` and `String` parameters. These parameters are annotated with `@JsonProperty`, which specifies that the `href` JSON property is mapped to the `ItemHref` parameter and the `name` JSON property is mapped to the `String` parameter.

This allows Jackson to use the constructor to create instances of the Item class from JSON, and to automatically deserialize the href property as an instance of ItemHref.

You can find more information about using Jackson's annotations for custom deserialization in the [Jackson documentation.](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations)